# How to Find Closest Date to Today From Date Attribute Of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know how I can selects and apply new class like `class= "c-1" , class= "c-2",...` based on date sequence to each next comming dates?

```js
var todayDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
```

```css
div {
  height: 60px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}

.c-1 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-date="2018-01-12"></div>
<div data-date="2018-01-22"></div>
<div data-date="2018-02-02"></div>
<div data-date="2018-02-07"></div>
<div data-date="2018-02-10"></div>
<div data-date="2018-02-15"></div>
<div data-date="2018-04-17"></div>
<div data-date="2018-05-11"></div>
```

Comment: `c-1` for day 1, `c-2` for day 2 and so on?

Comment: Do you want the class C-1 on the closest date or? what is the expected result?

Comment: You have not shown the javascript code that you are using. Basically you convert all dates into Date objects and store them in array and run a for loop where you maintain the time difference between current date and the date at current index. The closest date would be the Date with smallest time difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can use `filter()` to retrieve the divs which have a date greater than today, then add the class them.

> Let's say you want to list 3 next appointment date or more do I have to repeat the function?

To do that you can use `slice()` on the result of the above mentioned `filter()` to get the nearest 3 dates.

> how about today? I change your code to `>= today` to include today as well but still getting dates listed from after today

If you want to include today you will need to compare the dates only, removing the times. You can use `setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)` to equalise them all. Try this:

```js
var today = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
$('div').filter(function() {
  return new Date($(this).data('date')).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) >=  today;
}).slice(0, 3).addClass('c-1');
```

```css
div {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}

.c-1 {
  background: #C00;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-date="2018-01-12">2018-01-12</div>
<div data-date="2018-01-22">2018-01-22</div>
<div data-date="2018-02-02">2018-02-02</div>
<div data-date="2018-02-07">2018-02-07</div>
<div data-date="2018-02-10">2018-02-10</div>
<div data-date="2018-02-15">2018-02-15</div>
<div data-date="2018-04-17">2018-04-17</div>
<div data-date="2018-05-11">2018-05-11</div>
```

Note that I amended the CSS slightly only so the result was easier to see in the snippet.

Comment: How will this code return the Closest date.. I think divs do not have the dates in sorted order

Comment: @TarunGupta not sure what you mean. The div dates are clearly in order. Even if they weren't it could easily be fixed by sorting them

Comment: By closest date what I mean is the time difference between today and the div-date should be least amongst all. And its not mentioned anywhere that they are in sorted order.. that's why I mentioned it.

Comment: Thanks a losy for this Rory but how about next divs? I mean I am getting c-1 but how about other>

Comment: @Suffii the result of `filter()` will contain all relevant divs where the date is after today. If you still want to add incremental class attributes, I'd ask for what reason, as it's generally not a good idea

Comment: @TarunGupta I see your point, however I'm going to assume the OP simply means the next data greater than today.

Comment: let me please make this easier. Let's say you want to list 3 next appointment date or more do I have to repeat the function?

Comment: and just one minor thing! how about today? I change your code to ` >= today` to include today as well but still getting dates listed from after today

Comment: @Suffii I updated the answer based on those rules. To get the current day onwards you'll need to compare the dates without including the time. To get the next three dates after the closest, you can use `slice()`.

Comment: Great Thanks  a lots